# Cannot to write in one goroutine and read from another indefintely

Tags: go, goroutine

I am in the process of learning go, and I am having trouble with `goroutines`. Here is my code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var counter = 0
var wg = sync.WaitGroup{}

func main() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    go func() {
        for range ticker.C {
            // wg.Add(1)
            // defer wg.Done()
            counter++
            fmt.Println(counter)
            //wg.Done()
        }
    }()

    ticker2 := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 2)
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        for range ticker2.C {
            //defer wg.Done()
            fmt.Println(counter)
        }
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Basically, I would like to have:

- a global variable called `counter`
- one `goroutine` that keeps updating this counter every one 1 second
- another `goroutine` that keeps printing this counter every two seconds

Playground is [here](https://play.golang.org/p/9PLpwqaA3LG)
I tried to play with `WaitGroup` but I did not manage to have this working.
With this level of code, I have the following warning:

```
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x0000011d8318 by goroutine 8:
  runtime.convT2E64()
```

Another question is this thread safe? I mean, can I safely use counter in the main method outside of the two groroutines?

Comment: You're calling `wg.Add(1)` once and calling `wg.Done()` inside a loop. Don't call `wg.Done` until, well, you're actually done.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks. I am updating my code. Now, I have displayed: WARNING: DATA RACE

Comment: @tcoder01: yes, you have a data race. You cannot read and write the same value concurrently.

Comment: You need to call `Add` before calling `Wait` on a `sync.WaitGroup`.

Comment: I do not want to spoil this whole thing, but the overall approach is massively suboptimal: if all you want it a shared counter, use the `atomic` package as in https://gobyexample.com/atomic-counters Using channels would be idiomatic, but tricky here. But even using a simple read/readwrite lock would make your code much simpler conceptually. You lock RW before you increment, unlock immediately after; you lock R to read out the value, unlock immediately after, then print.

Comment: @JimB thanks. Any tips on how to fix this ? I have read about `sync.RWMutex{}`, and I am willing to study it more. My concern is: what if I have read operation that are a lot more frequent than write operations. Are you suggesting to lock `counter` on every read operation? will this delay the write ? Sorry, I come from js background with no experience in concurrency

Comment: Use a Mutex. If there are a lot more reads than writes, use an RWMutex. Yes, you need a lock of some sort for any read or write operation. I'm not sure what there is to study, there's not much to it.

Comment: @OlegSklyar Thanks a lot! I needed this explanation :)

Comment: @OlegSklyar: having looked at massive amounts of production Go code over many years, I would say that channels are _not_ idiomatic for mutual exclusion around a single value, nor is sync/atomic. You will almost always find a simple mutex around a shared value.

Comment: [Mutexes](https://gobyexample.com/mutexes) and [Atomic Counters](https://gobyexample.com/atomic-counters) might be helpful reads.

Comment: I assume this is just an experiment, yes? Otherwise you can just compute the counter's value from delta T. You don't need an actual counter.

Comment: @JimB I must say I do not see a trivial solution with channels either, but I am surprised why would you prefer a mutex to atomic in this case?

Comment: @Peter for now, this is just an experiment. In the future, instead of counter, I need to update a global struct state recurrently. The global state will be available to read operations with various frequency

Comment: @OlegSklyar: in the case of a simple counter, I would usually give atomic operations a pass, as the implementation is pretty straightforward. In the general case of shared values, a mutex is usually easier to reason about and avoids errors using the variety of other atomic functions. Only when proven that atomic operations are needed, via performance benchmarking, or other particular requirements, would atomic operations be added.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers :)  Things are clearer for me now

Comment: @tcoder01 I think what you want to implement is similar to the [Mutexes](https://gobyexample.com/mutexes) example from [Go By Example](https://gobyexample.com/), which is clearly explained.

Comment: @elmiomar exactly thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way may be to send message to 2nd gorutine when it comes time to print.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Start");
    counter := 0

    printChannel := make( chan int)
    done := make(chan struct{} )

    go func(done <-chan struct{}, printChannel chan<- int  ){
        timer := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
        bDone := false;
        for !bDone {
            select {
            case <-timer.C:
                counter++
                if counter%2 == 0 {
                    printChannel <- counter
                }
            case <-done:
                bDone=true
            }
        }
    }(done, printChannel)

    go func(done <-chan struct{}, printChannel <-chan int ){
        bDone:=false
        for !bDone{
            select {
            case n := <-printChannel:
                fmt.Print(n, " ");
            case <-done:
                bDone=true
            }
        }
    }(done,printChannel)


    //whatever logic to stop
    go func() {
        <- time.After(21*time.Second)
        done <- struct{}{}
    }()

    <-done

    fmt.Println("\nEnd");

}
```

Note that here there is 3rd gorutine just to finish the example

Output:

```
Start
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 
End
```

To improve it, you can do it without bDone variable, you can stop Ticker and add appropriate message when gorutine exists.
Or you may want to test 'break' with label to exit for loop.
You can test effect when you use close(done) channel instead of sending message to it.
Also, if you are ready to relax read/write order, you can remove printChannel and make 2nd gorutine use another ticker that pings every 2 seconds.